# Odoo - way to extend core Odoo module?

Tags: inheritance, odoo

I want to extend `class configmanager(object)` (it is located in `/openerp/tools/config.py`), which is not an addon class, but base class that handles Odoo configuration. Is there some good way to inherit it safely, so I would not need to modify source code directly?

P.S. I need to override one method of that class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a monkey-patch. Here you have an example: https://github.com/OCA/report-print-send/blob/8.0/base_report_to_printer/report_service.py

Note that a monkey-patch is applied even if your addon is installed or not. So you can check if your addon is installed inside your method. If your addon is not installed then call to original method. Remember that methods in python are objects.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems its not working for configmanager class, because it is activated before odoo is fully loaded. So it seems to always load original method first, because that method is used to load addons path, which is not visible until it is loaded and module to modify addons path loading is in addons path..:)

Comment: What do you have to extend? What method do you need to overwrite?

Comment: I was thinking to extend/override this method: `_check_addons_path` (in openerp/tools/config.py). But might also need to override `_parse_config` or `load` methods, so ConfigParser would let me put expression of path, not just actual path (for example path with wilcard, so it would understand there are multiple paths instead of one).

Comment: I recommend you to use symlinks to get addons you want in one path and use this one in addons_path config parameter. Then you don't need to change/extend any code

Comment: But don't I need to update symlinks if content in paths change? Like if I would add additional addon in path that symlink is connected (I mean after symlink was made)

Comment: If a new addon is added, yes. But you can symlink only addons you want to install. You select which addons are available for installing.